# SublimeText3 setting (configuration) manner

Tags: sublimetext3

I am new to SublimeText, use SublimeText3.
Along with the daily usage, I'm developing some plug-in, so I'd like to understand the manner deeply.

What I found strange is opening Preferences > Settings - Default,
a file **Preferences.sublime-settings** located at `Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Default`.

However, there is actually no such a directory, so I assume this is a binary hardcoded Virtual directory/File.

Also, I noticed, there is a (non virtual) User directory and **Preferences.sublime-settings** where we can edit.

I think this is a very smart method to let the user preserve the default setting and override the configuration.

So far I just guessed like this, and I'd like to confirm my understandings here.

When a plugin is developed, the default setting is placed in the plugin folder, and a user-setting file is automatically created in the User folder. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Packages are run directly from the `*.sublime-package` files, located in the executable path I believe. These are simply renamed zips. You can override files by creating the proper folder and file name in the packages folder. Settings are loaded in the following order. First the `Default` package, then any plugins installed (in alphabetical order), finally the `User` directory. So anything specified in the `User`directory will override/merge with anything preceding it.

With that out of the way, yes you should map the default settings to your plugins directory and the user ones to the user directory. The user setting file is not automatically created. For example, the following is an entry from `Main.sublime-menu`

```
{
    "command": "open_file", "args":
    {
        "file": "${packages}/User/Preferences.sublime-settings",
        "contents": "// Settings in here override those in \"Default/Preferences.sublime-settings\",\n// and are overridden in turn by file type specific settings.\n{\n\t$0\n}\n"
    },
    "caption": "Settings – User"
}
```

So when you first select the menu, it will try to create the file. If it doesn't exist, it should fill it with specified content.